# dll not found error when running ROS2 examples, any node, publish from command line on Windows 10

Tags: ros2, windows10, talker, ros-bouncy, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am setting up ROS2 Bouncy on Windows10 and already encountered the following problem while compiling from source: [ROS2 fails to build many packages on Windows 10](https://answers.ros.org/question/302045/ros2-fails-to-build-many-packages-on-windows-10/), which I solved.

---

EDIT: I found [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/301140/ros2-windows-failed-to-load-shared-library-of-rmw-implementation/) to be the same issue.

---

Now, my code compiles and I want to test the examples. But when I run the talker example node, it gives me this output:

```
cd \dev\ros2
call install\local_setup.bat
ros2 run demo_nodes_py talker
>>> [rcutils|error_handling.c:155] rcutils_set_error_state()
This error state is being overwritten:

  'failed to load shared library of rmw implementation. Exception: Cannot load library: C:\dev\ros2\install\bin/rmw_fastrtps_cpp.dll, at c:\dev\ros2\src\ros2\rmw_implementation\rmw_implementation\src\functions.cpp:135'

with this new error message:

  'failed to load shared library of rmw implementation. Exception: Cannot load library: C:\dev\ros2\install\bin/rmw_fastrtps_cpp.dll, at c:\dev\ros2\src\ros2\rmw_implementation\rmw_implementation\src\functions.cpp:135'

rcutils_reset_error() should be called after error handling to avoid this.
<<<
```

With the error message above repeating many times...

```
>>> [rcutils|error_handling.c:155] rcutils_set_error_state()
This error state is being overwritten:

  'failed to load shared library of rmw implementation. Exception: Cannot load library: C:\dev\ros2\install\bin/rmw_fastrtps_cpp.dll, at c:\dev\ros2\src\ros2\rmw_implementation\rmw_implementation\src\functions.cpp:135'

with this new error message:

  'failed to load shared library of rmw implementation. Exception: Cannot load library: C:\dev\ros2\install\bin/rmw_fastrtps_cpp.dll, at c:\dev\ros2\src\ros2\rmw_implementation\rmw_implementation\src\functions.cpp:135'

rcutils_reset_error() should be called after error handling to avoid this.
<<<
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\ros2\install\lib\demo_nodes_py\talker-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('demo-nodes-py==0.5.1', 'console_scripts', 'talker')()
  File "C:\dev\ros2\install\Lib\site-packages\demo_nodes_py\topics\talker.py", line 39, in main
    rclpy.init(args=args)
  File "C:\dev\ros2\install\Lib\site-packages\rclpy\__init__.py", line 27, in init
    args if args is not None else sys.argv)
RuntimeError: Failed to init: failed to load shared library of rmw implementation. Exception: Cannot load library: C:\dev\ros2\install\bin/rmw_fastrtps_cpp.dll, at c:\dev\ros2\src\ros2\rmw_implementation\rmw_implementation\src\functions.cpp:135, at c:\dev\ros2\src\ros2\rcl\rcl\src\rcl\rcl.c:92
```

EDIT: The exact same output is generated when I use `demo_nodes_cpp`. Also, when writing my own simple publisher in python, I get this error as well.

My rmw_implementation as well as all other packages (except for connext-related ones) compiled without error. Also, I find the `rmw_fastrtps_cpp.dll` in the given path (`C:\dev\ros2\install\bin/rmw_fastrtps_cpp.dll`). (It bugs me, that the path has mixed forward and backslashes.)

Maybe, I missed something in my setup?
EDIT: Does this have to do with environment variables? If so, is there a list of variables which should be set?

---

EDIT: I managed to isolate the error to the ros init call:

```
def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args) # error produced by this line of code
    ...
```

So somehow, when calling `rlcpy.init()`, the `rmw_fastrtps_cpp` dll fails to load. But why? Is there a connection to using `OpenSplice`?

---

EDIT: Even when calling

```
ros2 topic pub /chatter std_msgs/String "data: Hello world"
```

from command line, the following (similar) error occurs:

```
...
>>> [rcutils|error_handling.c:155] rcutils_set_error_state()
This error state is being overwritten:

  'failed to load shared library of rmw implementation. Exception: Cannot load library: C:\dev\ros2\install\bin/rmw_fastrtps_cpp.dll, at c:\dev\ros2\src\ros2\rmw_implementation\rmw_implementation\src\functions.cpp:135'

with this new error message:

  'failed to load shared library of rmw implementation. Exception: Cannot load library: C:\dev\ros2\install\bin/rmw_fastrtps_cpp.dll, at c:\dev\ros2\src\ros2\rmw_implementation\rmw_implementation\src\functions.cpp:135'

rcutils_reset_error() should be called after error handling to avoid this.
<<<
Failed to init: failed to load shared library of rmw implementation. Exception: Cannot load library: C:\dev\ros2\install\bin/rmw_fastrtps_cpp.dll, at c:\dev\ros2\src\ros2\rmw_implementation\rmw_implementation\src\functions.cpp:135, at c:\dev\ros2\src\ros2\rcl\rcl\src\rcl\rcl.c:92
```

---

I use OpenSplice 6.7, MS Visual Studio 2017 (v15.7.6), Python 3.7, Qt5 5.10.0 (but I have also installed 5.10.1, 5.11.0, 5.11.1)
colcon:

```
colcon-cmake 0.2.3: up-to-date
colcon-core 0.3.9: up-to-date
colcon-defaults 0.2.0: up-to-date
colcon-devtools 0.2.1: up-to-date
colcon-library-path 0.2.0: up-to-date
colcon-metadata 0.2.0: up-to-date
colcon-notification 0.2.5: up-to-date
colcon-output 0.2.2: up-to-date
colcon-package-information 0.2.1: up-to-date
colcon-package-selection 0.2.0: up-to-date
colcon-parallel-executor 0.2.2: up-to-date
colcon-pkg-config 0.1.0: up-to-date
colcon-powershell 0.3.3: up-to-date
colcon-python-setup-py 0.2.0: up-to-date
colcon-recursive-crawl 0.2.0: up-to-date
colcon-ros 0.3.3: up-to-date
colcon-test-result 0.3.0: up-to-date
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302167/dll-not-found-error-when-running-ros2-examples,-any-node,-publish-from-command-line-on-windows-10/) by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2018-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got rid of this issue by:

1. First setting my locale from German to English, then rebuilding from source and ignoring opensplice (as I actually do not need it). I do not know, if this step was really necessary.
2. Reinstalling `tinyxml2` as the respecting dll was not missing but unloadable. Actually, I followed [these hints](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Rclpy-Import-error-hint) and reinstalled the dependencies `asio`, `eigen`, `tinyxml-usestl` and `tinyxml2`.

See also this issue as info: [FastRTPS fails to find asio and tinyxml2 on Windows](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/516); and this [info](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Windows-Development-Setup/_compare/d4de94d08ff5094ea1ef5a27b6a83fb9b6d6e47f...e82818163c6c99b8bb53b972e8de841909ec20ac) when you encounter problems uninstalling dependencies. I had issues reinstalling tinyxml2, so I had to remove the respecting registry entry manually because chocolatey would not install it otherwise.

Following these steps, the talker and listener nodes run as expected.

---

Originally posted by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) with karma: 200 on 2018-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2018-09-10**:
Glad you got it working!
If you get a chance, could you try building a workspace from scratch using the german locale ? It would be valuable to know if there are issues with UTF-8 locales other than english.